# Distribute N rows to m instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, containers, distributed-computing

I have N rows in a table residing in a DB and each row refers to a processing workflow that would need independent processing.

There are M processes deployed in containers that can work on 1 such row at a time.

The current approach used has a **single non containerized process** that picks the rows and enqueues each into a queue Q. Q is subscribed by all M active worker processes

Is there a way to make the system fully containerized - I mean even **remove the non containerized single instance process that populates the queue**?

Comment: That seems like it should be possible; what have you already tried and what problem are you having?  If the original data source is a local file then the setup you currently have might be a good setup (running a non-Docker process, with direct access to the local filesystem, and network access to the compute system; you don't need to prefix the load command with `sudo docker run -v ...`).

Comment: @DavidMaze: The table reside in a DB that is accessible to all the containers mentioned. Updated the question, thanks